# How to identify unused Postgres views?

Tags: postgresql

In an effort to do database house cleaning, would like to be able to identify which Postgres 15 database views have not been queried in some time.

While I have found how to identify unused tables and indexes in Postgres 15, I have not found a way to do this with views (materialized and non-materialized views)

Comment: A regular view is just a predefined query over a table or tables. This means the activity takes place on the table(s). You would have to look at the Postgres logs to see how often the view query is run to see that side of the equation.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question. If it still gets closed, you might want to try at [DBA.SE]

Comment: @AdrianKlaver For more context, Views, Routines, Procedures are all database code. I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to know which are no longer called by anything. Capturing and querying logs was my fallback if nothing exists out of the box, in a pg extension, etc.

Comment: Sure they are doing the same thing logging the statements. See [pgstatements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) and [pgaudit](https://www.pgaudit.org/) as examples. You will still need to query the results fro specific objects. There is a stats view for functions [pg_stat_user_functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-USER-FUNCTIONS-VIEW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method ended up working well:

1. Log all queries that are executed by setting the Postgres setting `log_statement = 'all'`. This will generate file-based logs on the file system.
2. Wait a sufficient period of time e.g. 30 days where a view is expected to be accessed were it still used by the application, end user, etc.
3. Import logs file into a temp table
4. Do a left join from this table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views` to the temp table, comparing all of the databases’s views (which are all found in the metadata table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views`) to the list of view names that were accessed in the last of 30 days. For any views not found in the logs data that you imported into the temp table, those are the views that were not accessed/used in the last 30 days and can be potentially removed.

Comment: How did you join the SQL statement texts against the views?

Comment: @Bergi: I imported the log files into a temp table (step 3) so I could then join them against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views (step 4)

Comment: Yeah, but can you share the SQL query of that JOIN please? I'm curious how you extracted the view names from the logs.

Comment: It depends, for us, all of our views start with "view_" in their name, so we just used unix commands e.g. grep, into a file. Any way of parsing files would work e.g. even Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the distinct nature of views as query templates in PostgreSQL 15, identifying unused views requires a strategic approach. Views don't have separate data storage like tables do, so an evaluation strategy that is specific to views is required. A comprehensive picture of query activity is provided by setting `log_statement = 'all'`, which may provide information about rarely used views. Uncovering patterns of view usage involves parsing and analysing logs using programmes like `pgBadger` or `pgFouine`. Despite not having precise usage information, the `pg_stat_user_functions` view offers insights into user functions, especially those connected to views. In view tables, adding a "accessed_at" timestamp column and updating it during each query can provide organic usage insights for proactive tracking, subject to coding changes.
Applications' source code, reports, and queries can all be manually analysed to yield actionable context-specific insights. Exploring third-party monitoring tools may also include evaluating the usefulness of the views, leading to a thorough strategy to precisely and accurately find underutilised views.